# Parse.com security: can I save an object and claim it's another user's?

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform

I'm looking at [this example](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-associations) of modeling a blog system using javascript, code snippet copied as below:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();

// Make a new post
var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
var post = new Post();
post.set("title", "My New Post");
post.set("body", "This is some great content.");
post.set("user", user);
post.save(null, {
  success: function(post) {
    // Find all posts by the current user
    var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
    query.equalTo("user", user);
    query.find({
      success: function(usersPosts) {
        // userPosts contains all of the posts by the current user.
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It basically creates a post object and sets the current user object to its `user` field. To show all blog posts by the current user, it queries all blog posts with the `user` field set to the current user.

But since the `User` table by default is read only to all users, wouldn't this be problematic that a malicious user (`X`) can create random posts and "claim" that they are create by another user (`Y`), by setting the `user` field of those posts to `Y` as he queries from the `User` table? So the consequence would be that when the system shows posts for user `Y`, he would see all his true posts in addition to the post that was "forged" by `X`.

Is the mitigation that the `User` table needs to be ACL'd somehow? But if it is the solution, then why is the default behavior that an arbitrary user can see the entire `User` table?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Parse.com or what they do, but I would assume that there is some sort of authentication procedure as a user, where you are given a token of some sort (probably held in a cookie or localstorage) that gets passed along with the post to ensure that the user you claim to be has been authenticated on your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Code is your friend here.

In this case you want a `beforeSave` handler that locks the `user` field to the currently authenticated user on new objects, and rejects the save if they're updating a post and trying to change the `user` field (or just using ACLs to prevent everyone except the post owner from modifying Post rows).

Something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Post', function(request, response) {
  var post = request.object;
  var user = request.user;
  if (post.isNew()) {
    post.set('user', user);
    response.success();
  } else {
    // any special handling you want for updates, e.g.:
    if (post.dirty('user')) {
      response.error('Cannot change the owner of a Post!');
    } else {
      response.success();
    }
  }
});
```

My recommended approach to handling updates for something like a "Post" would be to prevent all updates. In the "Set permissions" for the class in the Data Browser I would change the following:

```
Update : Disabled
Delete : Disabled
```

To disable something just untick the "Any user can perform this action". Optionally you might want to assign a Role like "Administrator" or "Moderator" to allow those people to directly update/delete items.

These functions would then only be possible from Cloud Code when `useMasterKey()` is used, e.g.:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('deletePost', function(request, response) {
  var postID = request.params.postID;
  var query = new Parse.Query('post');
  query.get(postID).then(function (post) {
    if (post) {
      // post found
      var postOwner = post.get('user');
      if (postOwner.id == request.user.id) {
        // we let the owner delete their own posts

        // NOTE: need to use the master key to modify/delete posts
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

        post.destroy().then(function () {
          // TODO: delete all replies too?
          response.success();
        }, function (error) {
          response.error(error);
        });
      } else {
        response.error('Only the owner of a post can delete it!');
      }
    } else {
      // post not found, might as well respond with success
      response.success();
    }
  }, function (error) {
    response.error(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: That's a cool solution. Thanks. Can I alternatively ACL the user object on the client side so that only the authenticated user can get and set its user object? The other reason I like client side ACL is that it makes me feel uncomfortable to expose the user table to the world. People can do a lot of interesting things with it. I just don't know if there's some problem with ACL'ing the user table as I proposed.

Comment: It is often a good idea to set the whole table to deny reads (ACLs on individual items will override this). The issue then is that if you need to query it you will have to use a Cloud Function with `userMasterKey()`. Also at some point the user ID of other users will be exposed, don't rely on trying to hide that client side, use the Class Security and ACLs and `beforeSave` handlers to do security properly.

Comment: Thanks Tim. If you can incorporate this in your answer above that'll be great. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> But since the User table by default is read only to all users,
>   wouldn't this be problematic that a malicious user can create random
>   posts and "claim" that they are create by another user, by setting the
>   user field to the other user?

You can play around with curl to explore this.

IMO - you are right about world read on the _User class. So what. That is read.

When it comes to POST action, you are going to need an authenticated session as the user in question. You cant just spuuf things by claiming that u are a user that you read on the table.

try curl posts without an established session as the user. You will get a 403 or some 'illegal access' response.

Comment: Robert, I guess you haven't fully understood my question. I updated it. See if it's clearer now.